# Can std::ranges be used with std::list

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I note that many algorithms can be used with ranges allowing the use of members of custom types, rather than needing lambda functions. So, am curious whether `std::ranges` can be used efficiently with `std::list<>`. I am cognisant that `std::list<>` is not the go to data structure for such algorithms, but for other issues, it is the better for my purpose.

Comment: `std::list` is a range, why not?

Comment: I think the operating word in the question is "efficiently". Iirc ranges are lazily evaluated and a lot of operations are required to be constant time, so I would guess the answer is yes.

Comment: @康桓瑋, I had doubts, because std::list isn't sequential in memory, all examples used arrays and vectors.

Answer (score 6):

In C++20, different ranges can be subdivided into
[`input_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/input_range),
[`forward_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/forward_range), [`bidirectional_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/bidirectional_range), [`random_access_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/random_access_range), and [`contiguous_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/contiguous_range) base on their iterator types. The more refinement of the range, the more operations it supports and the more efficient its performance.

`std::list` is a `bidirectional_range`, so *any* C++20 rangified algorithm that requires a `bidirectional_range` and below can be applied to it.

Take [`ranges::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/transform) in `<algorithm>` as an example

```
template<ranges::input_range R, std::weakly_incrementable O,
         std::copy_constructible F, class Proj = std::identity>
  requires /* */
constexpr unary_transform_result<ranges::borrowed_iterator_t<R>, O>
transform(R&& r, O result, F op, Proj proj = {});
```

which explicitly requires that `R` must model `input_range`. Since `std::list` models a more refined `bidirectional_range`, it has all the operations supported by `input_range` and will work well with this algorithm.

Again, take the range adaptor [`ranges::transform_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/transform_view) in `<ranges>` as an example

```
template<ranges::input_range V, std::copy_constructible F>
  requires /* */
class transform_view : public ranges::view_interface<transform_view<V, F>>;
```

which only requires an `input_range`, so it can be used with `std::list`. It's worth noting that most range adaptors only require the underlying range to model `input_range` (only a few require `forward_range`), so `std::list` will also work well with them.

As for efficiency, since `std::list` only supports forward and backward operations, applying C++20 range utilities to it is less efficient than applying it to a `random_access_range` such as `std::vector`, but it definitely works.

Comment: Thank you for that comprehensive response and for introducing me to borrowed_iterator_t

Comment: In fact, `borrowed_iterator_t` has nothing to do with this answer.